Connecting Spark running on Docker to remote Hive running on localhost
I have an Apache Spark cluster running on docker, and I have hive running on my localhost. I want to connect them in order to ingest data from hive by spark cluster.
I tried the following in my pyspark script:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Ingest Data") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://host.docker.internal:9083") \
    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

but I already know that config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse") is incorrect, because it is referring to a folder on my localhost and not the container.
Is there a way to actually connect spark running in docker containers to hive running on localhost.

Refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789332/connecting-hive-to-from-spark-in-intellij question, you would need to follow steps similar to those in the answer, consider that you need to connect a remote hive setup from spark.

You can use pyhive to connect to hive server and use it below for sample, then you don't need to know the warehouse dir, for your current pyspark code just as usual:
from pyhive import hive

host = "host.docker.internal" # thrift server host
port = 10000                  # default thrift server port should be 10000

conn = hive.Connection(host=host, port=port)

# show databases
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
    databases = cursor.fetchall()

print("Databases:")
for db in databases:
    print(db[0])

# select * from test_table
table_name = "test_table"

query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} LIMIT 10"
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

print(f"\nTop 10 rows from {table_name}:")
for row in rows:
    print(row)

conn.close()


By the way, you need to install pyhive related modules using pip:
pip install pyhive thrift thrift_sasl


thanks, it worked, but I want to know if using pyhive instead of leveraging the capabilities of spark especially when dealing with big data is ok.

For your case, there are two seperated systems, one for Spark, another for Hive, after you get data from Hive you can use all features from Spark to process the data, just like you read data from a CSV file.
